# How to get only distinct values based on one column from different tables - SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database that I imported to Google Data Studio, and I have made the following query to get the data from multiple tables:

```
SELECT sw.waybill_number, sw.order_id as sworder_id, sw.status, sw.cod, sw.id AS sw_id, sw.created_at as sw_ca, c.shipping_price, c.id as c_id, oi.id as oi_id, oi.created_at as oi_ca, oi.order_id as oiorder_id, oi.product_id as oip_id, p.created_at as p_ca, p.id as p_id, p.name
FROM shipping_waybills sw
JOIN cities c
ON sw.state = c.name_en
LEFT JOIN order_items oi
ON sw.order_id = oi.order_id
LEFT JOIN products p
ON oi.product_id = p.id;
```

However, there are multiple values related to the column i want (sw.waybill_number), but I only want one value, it doesn't matter which one.

How can I do that??

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Also be clear on the database you are using.  Is this MySQL or Data Studio?

Comment: Is `waybill_number` unique in the `shipping_waybills` table?

Comment: Replace the `order_items` table with a subquery that gets the most recent row for each `order_id`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column?noredirect=1&lq=1 for how to do that in MySQL.

Comment: What version of MySql? Sounds like a job for `row_number()`, but it's only available in 8.0 and later.

Comment: Do you mean there are multiple rows per `sw.waybill_number`?  "I only want one value, it doesn't matter which one."  One what?  Value or row?

Comment: I want one row corresponding to sw.waybill_number, and I don't care which row. I just want one.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't care which values are on each `sw.waybill_number`...

```sql
SELECT sw.waybill_number
, MIN(sw.order_id) as sworder_id
, MIN(sw.status) as status
, MIN(sw.cod) as cod
, MIN(sw.id) AS sw_id
, MIN(sw.created_at) as sw_ca
, MIN(c.shipping_price) as shipping_price
, MIN(c.id) as c_id
, MIN(oi.id) as oi_id
, MIN(oi.created_at) as oi_ca
, MIN(oi.order_id) as oiorder_id
, MIN(oi.product_id) as oip_id
, MIN(p.created_at) as p_ca
, MIN(p.id) as p_id
, MIN(p.name) as name

FROM shipping_waybills sw
  INNER JOIN cities c ON sw.state = c.name_en
  LEFT OUTER JOIN order_items oi ON sw.order_id = oi.order_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN products p ON oi.product_id = p.id

GROUP BY sw.waybill_number
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering my question. But, I tried this query, and it still gives me multiple values for sw.waybill_number. How to remove those duplicates?

Comment: Provide sample structure and data.

Comment: With the `GROUP BY` each `sw.waybill_number` will appear only once in the output.  You must have tried something other than what I posted.